How to create Simulink block e^2s
I am trying to simulate a specific block in Simulink using MATLAB, specifically the block represented by the expression e^(2s). I want to create this block visually in Simulink. I found an image online that shows how this block looks, and I would like to replicate it in my Simulink model. However, I’m not sure how to create this block effectively.
I would appreciate guidance on the steps involved in creating this block, including any specific parameters or settings I should use.


The image shows “τ”, but your text says “2”. Is that intentional?
